# How to display multiple elements to html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to print elements found by function, just the first one is being printed.

Tried multiple printing methods. For now `alert()` is working fine, but I can't copy the content.

```js
    function test() {
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("but b_yt");
       for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
          alert(x[i]);
       }
    }
```

Every other printing methods doesn't print at all, prints just first one or something like `[HTML Data Collection]`. `console.log` works, but it gives me the whole HTML code of button.

Comment: thats expected behaviour as `alert()` will stop any further execution until you click "ok" on dialogue

Comment: It is the right output for console.log.

Comment: Can I force console.log to print just link that is in the button?

Comment: Try setting `x` to `[...document.getElementsByClassName("but b_yt")]`, it will spread the HTML data collection into an array of elements

Comment: @GammaGames it gave me [object HTMLCollection] output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get href attributes this way:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('but b_yt');

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let element = elements[i];
    console.log(element.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be a noob approach
this will give you innerhtml of each h1

```
<h1 class="abc">hello</h1>
<h1 class="abc">helsfvdfbbdfbdlo</h1>
```

[image]`

```
var s = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');

for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[i].innerText);
}
```

Comment: This returns everything between tags, but not source of the link.